# in swift 4.1, how do you listen for when a view controller has finished rotating?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using the viewWillTransition function to detect rotation, but I want to add a closure to the completion event of the animation, or otherwise detect that the rotation has finished.

In previous swift versions there was a didRotate function but that's been deprecated.

Edit

```
public override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    // I want to add a delegate or closure here when the coordinator's animation is finished
}
```

Comment: Show your animation code and the closure you are talking about please.

Comment: the content of the closure could be anything, I just want to know how to add an event listener to the animation

Comment: The `viewWillTransition` is the listener. It will be called whenever you screen rotates. Your question still appears vague. What do you want to animate when you view rotate. Is it after rotation or before rotation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the viewWillTransition you have a completion block to show when the rotation has finished, to check when the animation has finished it has to be in the animation completion block.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

And inside you have to call the super. 
And the coordinator.animate where there is the completion block

```
super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (_) in

                // Code while it is transitioning

            }, completion: _ in
               // Completion block
            )
```